# Lebesgue integration and Riemann integration of a characteristic function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a closed nowhere dense set on $[0,1]$.

a) Is it true that $\chi_E$ is Lebesgue integrable?

b) is it true that $\chi_E$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $m(E)=0$?

I know that $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $f$ is continuous except on a set of measure 0.

By definition of nowhere dense - the interior of the closure  is empty - I think that b) is true. But not sure about a).

Also, please let me know if you think my reasoning for b) is incorrect.

Thanks.

Comment: What would the set $\{ x | 1_E(x) < \alpha \}$ be for various $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give details for b). Here is a proof: If $m(E)=0$ then $\chi_E$ is continuous a..e because it is continuous on $E^{c}$ (It is the constant function $1$ on this open set). Hence, it is RI. Conversely, if it is RI then it is continuous a.e.. If $x \in E$ then no interval around $x$ can be conatined in $E$ (becasue $E$ has no interior) and hence there is  a sequence $x_n$ in $E^{c}$ converging to $x$. But then $\chi_E (x_n) =0$ for all $n$ and $\chi_E(x)=1$. So $\chi_E$ is not continuous at any point $x$ of $E$. Since it is continuous a.e we must have $m(E)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

a. $E$ is closed and therefore measurable. As it is also included in $[0,1]$ which has a finite measure, $\chi_E$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What do you think about b)? Does my reasoning sound correct?